# ResourceHttpRequestHandler : "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/main.html]"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, custom-error-pages

I get 404 error and o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/main.html]" in logs.
APPLICATION PROPERTIES:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/main")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView showMainPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("main");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

PROJECT STRUCTURE:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90vTD.jpg)

After importing into pom.xml it still doesn't work.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```